# Creating a unique_ptr from ifstream in binary

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, unique-ptr

I wish to load an object saved in a binary file using ifstream. Currently the pointer is not initialized and the application crashes. I am not 100% sure how to do this with unique_ptr. I imagine I will have to release the old object before reading the values.

In my main constructor:

```
typedef unique_ptr<Character> charPTR;
myCharacter_ = charPTR(new Character());
```

I try to load it as so:

```
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myCharacter_), sizeof(myCharacter_));
```

Saving the object actually works:

```
    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&myCharacter_), sizeof(myCharacter_));
```

Thank you for any help, I am not really used to unique_ptr but I thought it represented my storage struct perfectly.

Comment: What is `Character`?

Comment: Use `myCharacter_.get()` rather than `&myCharacter_` and `sizeof(Character)` rather than `sizeof(myCharacter_)`.

Comment: Well I would mark it as correct since this works. Maybe you want to add an answer? Am I correct to think the reasoning is that, when using unique_ptr.get(), you are overwriting the pointer? Thank you very much for the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan Potter has already given you a solution but I'll tell you why it works and why it didn't before.

When you write out:

```
ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&myCharacter_), sizeof(myCharacter_));
```

You are taking the address of `myCharacter` which is a `std::unique_ptr` and casting that pointer to a `const char *` when it is in fact the object which *contains* that pointer. So what you have is basically equivalent to a `const char **` and you are casting it to a `const char *`.

By calling `myCharacter.get()` you are retrieving the stored raw pointer which is of `Character *` type (which I am assuming you have assured is identical in memory layout to a `char *`) and casting it to a `const char *`.

Now `ofstream` has an overload which takes a `const char *` and assumes it is a null terminated string and attempts to write that out. Yours isn't a null terminated string but by passing in `sizeof(Character)` (which I am assuming is equivalent to `sizeof(char)`) you assure it only tries to access one character anyway. You could perhaps make this more explicit by doing `*myCharacter.get()` and serialising the value type.

More generally, if `Character` really is just a `char` then I don't see any point in ever having a `unique_ptr` of it. The cost of copying a `char` is always going to be less than dereferencing that pointer and in fact the size of the pointer itself is always going to be far larger than the `char`.

Comment: Character is a struct of strings and ints etc. I don't use any virtual methods, it contains no pointers and such. I *believe* it is fine to do as I did? Currently it is working, so as long as I don't do funky stuff inside my struct, from what I read I should be ok... Thank you very much for the explanation though.